# Should I mark my question duplicate or delete it? If it's actually a duplicate

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36124363/deep-copying-objects-in-angular2) is the question.

The question wasn't supposed to be duplicate, but as there is no solution to the problem in exact way that I wanted, it becomes duplicate of the question referenced to be the original.

What would be the right action?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/305595​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ - Check the **What are the criteria for deletion?** part.

Comment: Do you think someone would search for your problem and be looking for a solution?  If they did, would they find the other post first, or would they find yours?  If they would find yours first, then your question becomes valuable as a signpost to "solution".

Comment: I think my question is concerned with `deep copying` in `Angular2` and the other is concerned with `angular.copy()` more specifically. So If someone doesn't know `Angular1` they would be searching for what I asked not the other. So I think my question stays.